# Overriding application root URL creates a page not available

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, onenote

I am following [this tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/OneNoteDev/Getting-Started-with-the-OneNote-API-ASP-NET-Edition) and four minutes in he simply runs the application- after I do the same I get "web page not available". I did everything like him and set override application root url, I set the start URL and then set the applicationhost.config like he did:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:www.onenotedemowebsite.com" />
```

Of course before I did any of those things, the MVC application worked fine while the binding info was left to localhost.
Can I get any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you didn't add the url to hosts file like they did in the video.

Open the file: `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` in Notepad(open as administrator).

Add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1     www.yoururl.com
```

Save and close the hosts file. Restart the browser and try again.

Comment: That was it, I was wondering where that hosts file was located...
Since I have multiple projects- can I now just put new names here or change this one?

Comment: Add new line for a new site in the hosts file.

Answer (score 2):

Have you changed your hosts file?

> %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

You should put a redirection from localhost to the site like this:

> 127.0.0.1       www.onenotedemowebsite.com

//EDIT: Was to late...